# Possible to pass jquery var to ruby/rails instance variable within .js.erb file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ok so I am calling a js.erb partial which is calling an html.erb partial.. However, I need to pass a variable from the jquery partial to the html.erb partial...

Basically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#aidmodel_brand').change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
      var brand = ($(this).text());
      $('#modeler').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "shared/model", :brand => @brand)) %>'); 
    });
  });
});
```

I want the var brand to somehow be assigned to the instance variable @brand so that I can pass the selected option from a drop menu to the rails partial to generate the next drop down menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this can't be done the way you want is that the Javascript in the js.erb is executed on the (client side), *after* the ruby is executed (on server).

So this -

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "shared/model", :brand => @brand)) %>
```

is executes on the server, and the resulting js is passed to the client, where much later, the following javascript is executed.

```
function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
      var brand = ($(this).text());
      ...
```

Now to achieve the requirement, you can render all the `brand` partials in the ruby code, and then let the js do the choosing. Something like -

```
 $('#modeler').html(<%= escape_javascript(Brand.all.each{|b| render(:partial => "shared/model", :brand => b)}.join('')) %>)

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#aidmodel_brand').change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
      var brand = ($(this).text());
      var brand_finder = "." + brand
      var brand_block = $('#modeler').find(brand_finder)
      brand_block.show()  
    });
  });
 });
```

And within the "shared/model" you can give the brand block a css class name that is same as the text in option:selected.